# List of Applications on Mac OS X

Tags: macos

Is there a way to find a list of all applications installed on a Mac in either `/Library` or `/System`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you've been doing something unusual with your system, your `/Applications` folder (and any `~/Applications` folders) **is** your list of installed programs.  Mac OS X doesn't have a central location where programs can register themselves as installed, the way Windows does.  If you're looking to uninstall something, you would drag it from `/Applications` to the trash, or you can use a program such as [AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com/) to help find any other parts of the app stored in `/Library` or `~/Library`.

If you use MacPorts, then you would also use the `port installed` command to see any programs it has installed.

`/System` only contains files placed in the system by Apple.  Regular apps do not write there.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering since Apple's "Archive and Install" upgrade feature only retains Apple-approved applications, so I wasn't sure if I could get a list or not.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't cover all installed applications, but simple enough and works for me:

```
find /Applications -type d -name '*.app' -prune -print
```

You can use above for `/Library` or `/System`.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `mdfind`:

```
mdfind kMDItemContentType=com.apple.application-bundle
```

It doesn't include applications inside other application bundles though. Also Spotlight doesn't index some directories, like directories that start with a period.

Another option is to use `lsregister`:

`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump|awk '$1=="path:"'`

The output might include applications that have already been deleted. You can avoid that by adding `-kill` to rebuild the Launch Services database, but it makes OS X show the warnings about opening applications for the first time again.